# Check if starting characters of a string are alphabetical in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

Is it possible, just using TSQL, to check if the first two characters of a varchar field are alphabetical?

I need to select from `my_table` only the rows having `my_field` beginning with two alphabetical chars. How can I achieve this?

Is it possible to use a regex?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You don't need to use regex, `LIKE` is sufficient:

```
WHERE my_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]%'
```

Assuming that by "alphabetical" you mean only latin characters, not anything classified as alphabetical in Unicode.

Note - if your collation is case sensitive, it's important to specify the range as `[a-zA-Z]`. `[a-z]` may exclude `A` or `Z`. `[A-Z]` may exclude `a` or `z`.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi - incorrect. In SQL Server, for most collations, the alphabet is in the order `aAbBcCdDeE...zZ`. Perhaps you're thinking of ASCII?

Comment: You're right. TBH, I have never had occasion to use a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: This is only for first and second letter, how can I do this for all chars?

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan - Would be better searched for/asked as a separate question, but okay, I'll answer. If you want to ensure that a column contains only alphabetical characters, a double-negative search condition would work: `NOT column LIKE '%[^a-Z]%'` - which says to **not** match the column if it contains any number of characters, a character *outside* the set `a-Z`, and any number of characters.

Comment: I am soo sorry @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I didn't read the question, thanx very much, I used the current pattern: NOT column LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z ]%'

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from my_table where my_field Like '[a-z][a-z]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE mail REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]';
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**