# How to add constraint on the SQL when the data type is nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning how to add the check constraint, but it did not really work as I expected.

So, I have a column limit, which actually require some constraints, as some of the user broke our system when they enter record back end.

Column '**limit**':
Constraint expected : If not NULL or Empty, then record must be float/numeric.

[image]

Can anyone help to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you use nvarchar and not Float/numeric?

Comment: Because we are still allowing them to enter empty, if the datatype is float/decimal, then it will be 0 by default. However, for us here, 0 means VALUE. Therefore, i just need to add constraint,when the value not empty or NULL, then we need to make sure its is numeric. Because some user will try to add 'N/A' or any alphabet, but we wont allow

Comment: Use other new column in bit to set status of this column if empty or not. Are you able to do this?

Comment: I dont think so @Adinugraha Tawaqal, is this way not possible to do?

Comment: Based on your description, you need to use a NULLable float column. Although, you cannot represent 0 in a float column. You might prefer to use a DECIMAL column instead. What's the range of numbers that you are storing?

Comment: empty, NULL, and no range of number, I am storing that kind of record.

Comment: is it possible we check if it using the alphabet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677602/609990) to check numeric using ISNUMERIC(), and throw error if not. But this is bad design because you are not using database constraint but trigger validation.

I still suggest you add a new checklist column where user select by themself if CK_limit is empty or not.

Comment: is it possible if we use constraint to check if it use alphabet?

Comment: my_field LIKE '[a-Z][a-Z]%'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407529/check-if-starting-characters-of-a-string-are-alphabetical-in-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
Or you can use client side validations or you can use stored procedures to track this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `isnumeric()` for the constraint.  For instance, `isnumeric()` accepts the following as valid numbers:

- `'$'`
- `'.'`
- `'-'`
- `'3e4'`

Instead, use `try_convert()`.  You can do:

```
(try_convert(float, limit) is not null or
 limit is null or
 limit = ''
)
```

However, the right solution is to simply use the correct data type for the column.  Don't store numeric values in strings.